# Showing results of a SELECT statement including every 30-min range of the day, filling 0´s when no records exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `arrivals` like this:

```
HHMM      Car
----      ---
0001      01
0001      02
0001      03
0002      04
...
0029      20
0029      21
0030      22
...
0059      56
```

I need to know how many cars arrived at each range of 30 minutes. 
I wrote a query like this:

```
WITH    

PREVIOUS_QUERIES AS
(
-- in fact, "PREVIOUS_QUERIES" represent a sequence of queries where I get 
-- the timestamp HHMM and convert it in a range where HOURS = HH and 
-- MINUTES_START can be 0 (if MM<30) or 30 (if MM>=30).
),

INTERVALS AS
(
SELECT
      TO_CHAR(HOURS,'FM00')||':'||TO_CHAR(MINUTES_START,'FM00')||' - '
        ||TO_CHAR(HOURS,'FM00')||':'||TO_CHAR(MINUTES_START +29,'FM00') AS INTERVAL,
    CAR

FROM
    PREVIOUS_QUERIES
)

SELECT
  INTERVAL, 
  COUNT (DISTINCT (CAR)),
  FROM INTERVALS
  GROUP BY INTERVAL
  ORDER BY INTERVAL
;
```

My query produces the following results.

```
Interval        Cars
-------------   ----
00:00 - 00:29     21
00:30 - 00:59     35
01:00 - 01:29     41
02:30 - 02:59      5
03:00 - 03:29     12
03:30 - 03:59     13
...
```

That means, if there are no arrivals in some interval, my query doesn´t show a line with Cars=0. I need these rows in my results:

```
01:30 - 01:59      0
02:00 - 02:29      0
```

How could I add these rows? Can it be done with a change on my query, or
should this query be completely rewritten?

What I imagine is that I should generate the 48 ranges of 30 minutes from '00:00-00:29' to '23:30-23:59' and then use them as a parameter for SELECT, but I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, much better now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just select those 48 values into another CTE, something like 'cteIntervals', and then adjust the final query to be something like:

```
SELECT
    I.Interval
    , NVL(Q.Cars, 0) Cars
FROM
    cteIntervals I
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            -- Your current query
        ) Q
    ON I.Interval = Q.Interval
```

This has the effect of creating a template for the final query to fit into.

For a slightly more dynamic solution you could look into producing `cteIntervals` using a recursive CTE, or you could store the values in a table, etc.

Comment: Chris, did you mean "insert" those 48 values into another CTE ?

Comment: Well, you already have a CTE called 'INTERVALS'; I'm picturing something like that, only it would contain all of the 48 values. The most basic way to do that would be `SELECT '00:00 - 00:29' FROM DUAL UNION SELECT '00:30 - 01:00' FROM DUAL UNION ...`, etc.

Comment: Ok Chris, I really needed this explanation for I´m on beginner level in SQL. Thanks for your answers.